# Gitlab pushing via https doesnt succed because of iptables

Tags: https, iptables, gitlab, freeze

I installed the Gitlab-Omnibus bundle and opened iptables for port 80, 443, 9418 and temp. even for 22. Why doesn't pushing via https work? When I put iptables in default open for everything it works.
Here are my rules for 80, 443, 22 and 9418

```
# 1. Allow incoming HTTP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT

# 2. Allow outgoing HTTP
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming HTTPS
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT

# 10. Allow outgoing HTTPS
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT

# allow git
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 9418 -j ACCEPT

#SSH: Client --> Server
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

The Result is:

```
Pushing to https://TLD/USER/REPO.git
POST git-receive-pack (448 bytes)
```

And then it just freezes. What do I need to open else?

I tried logging dropped packages but there is nothing with my ip?

I hope someone can help me..

Ok here are the rules for my logging:

```
#Logging
$IPTABLES -N LOGGING
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -j LOGGING
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
$IPTABLES -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
$IPTABLES -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

And here is the output:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Nov 13 18:43:13 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:LOGGING - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.20.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 37655 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 9418 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOGGING
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 10.20.0.0/16 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 37655 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
-A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
-A LOGGING -j DROP
-A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
-A LOGGING -j DROP
-A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
-A LOGGING -j DROP
-A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
-A LOGGING -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Comment: What's the output of `iptables-save`? How did you try logging the dropped packets and how did you try viewing them?

Comment: Please update the question itself with the output of the command `iptables-save`, after you've added the relevant logging rules.

Comment: I'm interested in the output of `iptables-save` since the order of the rules matters. Which log file have you read?

Comment: I read the syslog -> /var/log/syslog

Comment: As far as I can tell, the rules seem valid. Does other traffic work? Can you `ssh` into your computer? Perhaps you need to allow loopback traffic via `iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -o lo -j ACCEPT`. If you don't limit the logging rules, is anything logged?

Comment: So I changed the complete script with a little help from a friend and now everything seems to work, I'm going to post the new script here for feedback and people who are interested in the sulution ;)

Comment: Cool, do you know which change made the difference?

Comment: Not really, but I think a possible reason could be that the modprobe modules weren't loaded. Therefore the connectionstate based rules didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Devices
DEV0=eth0

#internal network
INT_NET=xxx.xxx.0.0/16
INT_NET_SECURE=xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24

#external network
EXT_NET=xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24

#path iptables
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
#path modprobe
MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe



case $1 in
        start)
        $0 stop

        echo "start ip-package-filter"

        # iptables-Modul
        $MODPROBE ip_tables

        # Connection-Tracking-Module
        $MODPROBE ip_conntrack
        $MODPROBE ip_conntrack_ftp 
        $MODPROBE ip_nat_ftp 
        $MODPROBE iptable_nat 

        #Standard-Policy - Deny everything except what we want
        $IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
        $IPTABLES -P OUTPUT DROP
        $IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP

        #slows down icmp for too much packages
        echo "5" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit


        #Kills packages with source route option
        echo "0">/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$DEV0/accept_source_route
        #Kills icmp forwarding
        echo "0">/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$DEV0/accept_redirects
        #Kills spoofed packages
        echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/$DEV0/rp_filter

        #Kills packages from 0.X.X.X
        echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/bootp_relay
        # TCP-FIN-Timeout (DoS-Attack)
        echo 30 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout
        #TCP-SYN max 3 answers
        echo 3 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries1
        #TCP-Package max 15x repetitions
        echo 15 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries2


        #Loopback-Communication
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT 
        $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o lo -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT 

        #ICMP: Client <--> Server
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
        $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

        #DNS: Server --> DNS-Server
        $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
        $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT


        # Allow incoming HTTP
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

        # Allow incoming HTTPS
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

        #SSH: Client --> Server (internal)
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -s $INT_NET -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT


        #SSH: Client --> Server
        #$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
        #$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

        #Update (apt)
        $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

        #TeamDrive
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 37655 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

        #Git
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9418 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT


        #Connection-Tracking for INPUT and OUTPUT CHAIN
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
        $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

        #Logging
        $IPTABLES -N LOGGING
        $IPTABLES -A INPUT -j LOGGING
        $IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
        $IPTABLES -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
        $IPTABLES -A LOGGING -j DROP



                echo "Firewall activated"

        ;;

        stop)
                $IPTABLES -F INPUT
                $IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
                $IPTABLES -F FORWARD
        ;;

        restart)
                $0 start
        ;;

        *)
                echo "Usage: $0 {startwd|stop|restart}"
        ;;

esac
```

Comment: This answer is not descriptive. It may helped you, but others may not understand why this is the accepted answer.